# Getting variable from queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a ModelAdmin class, to which I have added a custom action called add_50_credits as follows:

```
class TutorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    actions = ['add_50_credits']

    def add_50_credits(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(account_balance+=50)
```

What I am trying to do is add 50 to the account_balance of all users in the queryset. However, this code gives a syntax error. How do I get the variable account_balance for each object in the queryset and add 50 to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `F` objects.

```
from django.db.models import F
queryset.update(account_balance=F('account_balance') + 50)
```